# How to redraw only one view in Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

Is it somehow possible to force adapter to redraw only specific item?

Currently if I want to redraw the list, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which re-iterates through all the data-set and redraws all elements. What if I know exactly which element was updated and I want to redraw only that one?

Comment: you_view.invalidate() ?

Comment: But how do you access that view if it was generated by the adapter?

Comment: Before calling `invalidate()`, you need to update view's values (call `setText()` etc.) which is normally done in the adapter.

Comment: But the adapter calls `invalidate` by itself.

Comment: If you want to update only one cell of a listview... i don't see how to do it apart from calling notifydatasetchanged and in GetView() only update the view you want :/

Comment: By the way I think only the visible items' getView() methods will be called

Comment: @abbath what if I have many visible items and the items have quite complicated view structure. I want to redraw only 1 visible item.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is not for redrawing elements, it is for notifying the adapter, that the elements have changed in some way, for example there are more elements, or their data is set from an other class etc. Of course, the `ListView` (or other class), to which the adapter is connected will redraw the elements, becuase the Adapter is forced to tell him, its dataset is changed.
As Yume117 commented, for redrawing you can call one `View`'s `invalidate()` method (or even better `postInvalidate()`),

> postInvalidate(): 
>   Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle
>   through the event loop.

```
public void invalidate ()

Added in API level 1
Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().
```

You can call these methods on one view in the `Adapter`'s `getView()` method, or only call invalidate on the ListView (or other view) itself, and it will only redraw the visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method out of box, which is not so bad as not whole dataset gets re-iterated and not all elements gets redrawn, but just currently visible ones. These are usually not so many.

Answer (score 0):

You can create singletone object with Map. And then put every View of your object to this map. And after all, you can change this object, redraw your specified View (you have to know position) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.